# How to overwrite default social bookmarks in Liferay

Tags: liferay, bookmarks

In my liferay structure I have default social bookmarks with many options to share: facebook, twitter, delicious etc. But I want to have only facebook and twitter.
I do not have liferay app to manage plugins. I tried to put:

```
social.bookmark.types=facebook, twitter
```

in my portal-ext.properties but it didn't work.
Where and how can I change it?

Comment: Which version are you running? Did you restart after editing the properties file? And: Where's the typo - here or in your file system? The file is actually named `portal-ext.properties` (note the "-", not ".")

Comment: plus, this is a configuration issue, not a software development or code issue. You'll get better help at the Liferay forums or on Liferay's community slack channel. IMHO the question is [out of focus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for hints. It is liferay 7.0. Yes, I restared it, and of course my file name is portal-ext

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the property in portal-ext.properties without space after the comma: `social.bookmark.types=facebook,twitter`

More information, see: https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Social%20Bookmarks